Doctrine 3 'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' not working
How to handle default datetime values in doctrine entities?
I'm working with the following code:
#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'messages')]
class Message
{
    #[Column(name: 'sent_at', type: Types::DATETIME_IMMUTABLE, updatable: false, options: ['default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'])]
    private readonly DateTimeImmutable $sent_at;
    ...
}

and orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql seems to produce proper SQL
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  sent_at datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  message text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

but when I try to create such entity without manually setting sent_at (expecting it to use the default current timestamp)
$message = new Message($message);
$this->entity_manager->persist($message);
$this->entity_manager->flush();

I get this error:
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sent_at' cannot be null in vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Statement.php:55
What is causing this error, and how can I correctly set a default timestamp value for sent_at in Doctrine?
I’d like to avoid manually setting sent_at in the constructor if possible.
"doctrine/orm": "^3.0",
"doctrine/dbal": "^4.0",

Edit:
output of SELECT VERSION();: 10.4.28-MariaDB
To be precise, the reason is somewhere in PHP/Doctrine because
INSERT INTO `messages` (`message`) VALUES ('message')

correctly inserts row with current timestamp.

Can you please query SELECT VERSION(); and post the result?

If the PHP/Doctrine was doing the INSERT in that form then it wouldn't error. It appears that NULL is being inserted by Doctrine as the one way that this error would result. Here's the test I did https://dbfiddle.uk/4XivFDB1. I recommend creating a Doctrine Issue.

I see you have issue #11702
